Table or column matches object referenced in triggering statement
I have a table contract(id, employee_id, date_from, date_to, status) and trigger contract_ins. I need to be able to update a same table but other records.
INSERT INTO contract(0, 'A001', '01-01-2024', NULL, 'A');
 -- contract_ins => UPDATE contract SET status = 'I' WHERE id != nxt.id

send column 'status' is necessary for insert.
I read to docs
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statement-re-entrancy-triggers
If I should rethink my idea...

It isn't clear what nxt.id represents.  However, you should be able to create an insert trigger that executes an appropriate UPDATE statement.  If, as I suspect, nxt.id is the ID value for the newly inserted row, it isn't clear why you'd want to update every other row in the table so that the status is 'I'.  You've not shown whether there is a unique constraint on the employee_id.  Knowing Informix, it is easy to infer that the id column is serial type (SERIAL, BIGSERIAL, or — perish the thought — SERIAL8).  Please clarify the requirements.
